# Using Mass Effect 3 coalesced utility tool how can I unlock armors?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I am currently playing mass effect 3 on pc.. I already have ended it with default character and I am looking to play it again while being an adept and go for alternate ending. =) Now I really dont want to wait again and find those armor pieces.. I learned how to use the ME 3 coalesced utility tool but now aware of how to get the desired result.. =/ I want every armor piece/ armor for my new character unlocked! Now what command should I bind a key to! what should I write to let it know that I want all armors unlocked..?
please help me.. :)
and also can I add a command to bring console in-game..!

Thankyou.. your help will be appreciated and I am sure there are many looking for the answer.. =)

Comment: I think your question is too specific regarding the means of acquiring the armor. The console is a much better way to get it.

Answer (score 4):

To enable the console, browse to and open the file `\My Documents\BioWare\Mass Effect3\Config\BioInput.ini` (the full location is mentioned above) in any text editor (Notepad, for example), but **not with rich text editor** (Microsoft Word, OpenOffice Writer, WritePad, and the likes).
In the file you opened, search for `[Engine.Console]`, and add the line `ConsoleKey=`(Whatever key you want) just under it. This will bind console to a key.
Ok, so now that you have that done, enter the game as an Adept, enter console and type this command: `GiveAllArmor` 
**That does not involve coalesced, but it should give you all the armor.**
Hope this helps!

Comment: Probably a better idea than messing around with game files.

Answer (score 2):

biogame.ini > sfxgame > sfxplayercustomization

Component Armor piece listings:
armappearances = (multiple) helmetappearances = (multiple) legappearances = (multiple) shoulderappearances = (multiple) torsoappearances = (multiple)

Single Piece Armor: fullbodyappearances = (multiple)

To unlock, set the PlotFlag for the armor that you want to -1.

---

Casual appearances can be unlocked the same way as armor.

All casual appearances are located here:

biogame.ini > sfxgame > sfxplayercustomization > casualappearances = (multiple)

To unlock, set the PlotFlag for the armor that you want to -1.